# Upgrade Maven Version in Windows

Tags: maven

I want to upgrade to Maven latest version from 3.2.2v in windows. I know that there is a command as I used it before, but unable to recollect it now and haven't found in google even after an hour. So, can some one please help me with the command.

Thanks,
Likitha

Comment: An upgraded version can be downloaded https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Maven has no command to upgrade to Maven 3.X. You should download and extract new version.